# Difference between std::resize(n) and std::shrink_to_fit in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, containers, capacity

I came across these statements:

`resize(n)` – Resizes the container so that it contains ‘n’ elements.
`shrink_to_fit()` – Reduces the capacity of the container to fit its size and destroys all elements beyond the capacity.

Is there any significant difference between these functions? they come under vectors in c++

Comment: resize modifies the size of the container, shrink_to_fit does not. For normal usage you do not need to know about shrink_to_fit, it is only available to enable developers to manually increase the performance of their code.

Comment: Standard containers have a *size* and a *capacity*. The size is the current number of elements in the container, while the capacity is the amount of memory allocated (roughly). Resizing changes the size, `shrink_to_fit` changes the capacity.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between `capacity` and `size`?

Answer (score 13):

Vectors have two "length" attributes that mean different things:

- `size` is the number of usable elements in the vector. It is the number of things you have stored. This is a conceptual length.
- `capacity` is how many elements would fit into the amount of memory the vector has currently allocated.

`capacity >= size` must always be true, but there is no reason for them to be always equal. For example, when you remove an element, shrinking the allocation would require creating a new allocation one bucket smaller and moving the remaining contents over ("allocate, move, free").

Similarly, if `capacity == size` and you add an element, the vector could grow the allocation by one element (another "allocate, move, free" operation), but usually you're going to add more than one element.  If the capacity needs to increase, the vector will increase its capacity by *more than* one element so that you can add several more elements before needing to move everything again.

With this knowledge, we can answer your question:

- `std::vector<T>::resize()` changes the *size* of the array. If you resize it smaller than its current size, the excess objects are destructed. If you resize it larger than its current size, the "new" objects added at the end are default-initialized.
- `std::vector<T>::shrink_to_fit()` asks for the *capacity* to be changed to match the current size. (Implementations may *or may not* honor this request. They might decrease the capacity but not make it equal to the size. They might not do anything at all.) If the request is fulfilled, this will discard some or all of the unused portion of the vector's allocation. You'd typically use this when you are done building a vector and will never add another item to it. (If you know in advance how many items you will be adding, it would be better to use `std::vector<T>::reserve()` to tell the vector before adding any items instead of relying on `shrink_to_fit` doing anything.)

So you use `resize()` to change *how much stuff is conceptually in the vector.*

You use `shrink_to_fit()` to minimize the excess space the vector has allocated internally *without* changing how much stuff is conceptually in the vector.

Comment: Note that `shrink_to_fit` is not all-or-nothing. An implementation may reduce the capacity part way. For example consider an implementation that constrains vector capacity to powers of two.

Answer (score 5):

> `shrink_to_fit()` – Reduces the capacity of the container to fit its size and destroys all elements beyond the capacity.

That is a mischaracterization of what happens. Secifically, the *destroys all elements beyond the capacity* part is not accurate.

In C++, when dynamically memory is used for objects, there are two steps:

1. Memory is allocated for objects.
2. Objects are initialized/constructed at the memory locations.

When objects in dynamically allocated memory are deleted, there are also two steps, which mirror the steps of construction but in inverse order:

1. Objects at the memory locations destructed (for built-in types, this is a noop).
2. Memory used by the objects is deallocated.

The memory allocated beyond the *size* of the container is just buffer. They don't hold any properly initialized objects. It's just raw memory. `shrink_to_fit()` makes sure that the additional memory is not there but there were no objects in those locations. Hence, nothing is destroyed, only memory is deallocated.

Answer (score 2):

According to the C++ Standard relative to `shrink_to_fit`

> Effects: shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request to reduce capacity()
>   to size().

and relative to `resize`

> Effects: If sz < size(), erases the last size() - sz elements from the
>   sequence. Otherwise, appends sz - size() default-inserted elements to
>   the sequence.

It is evident that the functions do different things. Moreover the first function has no parameter while the second function has even two parameters. The function `shrink_to_fit` does not change the size of the container though can reallocate memory.